# displaying random questions at onces using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am creating a quiz app which has an array that includes five questions but i want the five questions to display randomly but all the 5 questions at the same time

```
const randomQuestion = (array) => {
    let random = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)]
    return random
}
const [current, setCurrent] = useState(() => randomQuestion(questions));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    const randomQuestion = (data) => {
      return data.sort(() => (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1));
    };
console.log(randomQuestion([2, 3, 4, 56, 7]));
    const [current, setCurrent] = useState(() => randomQuestion(questions))
```

Comment: I tried this exact code before it worked but it only shows just a question out of all the array instead of showing all the 5 questions at once

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/reactjs-playground-forked-njgj6d     i kinda experimented with it here so take a look

Answer (score 0):

Here's one using the [`array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method.

```js
array = ["Hello", "Hello2", "Hello3", "Hello4", "Hello5"];

let random = array.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);

console.log(random);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const randomizeArray = (array) => {
  const newArray = array.slice();
  
  for (let i = newArray.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [newArray[i], newArray[j]] = [newArray[j], newArray[i]];
  }
  
  return newArray;
};

const questions = [
  "Question 1",
  "Question 2",
  "Question 3",
  "Question 4",
  "Question 5"
];

const randomizedQuestions = randomizeArray(questions);
console.log(randomizedQuestions);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).